# Using Laravel Websocker with docker/ docker-compose.yml is not working

Tags: php, laravel, docker, websocket, docker-compose

I am developing a Laravel application. I am trying to use Laravel Websocket in my application, https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets. I am using Docker/ docker-compose.yml. Since the Laravel Websocket run locally on port 6001, I am having problem with integrating it with docker-compose. Searching solution I found this link, https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2002. I tried it but not working. Here is what I did.

I created a folder called workspace under the project root directory. Inside that folder, I created a file called, Dockerfile.

This is the content of Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 6001
```

In the docker-compose.yml file, I added this content.

```
workspace:
    port:
      - 6001:6001
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks something like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  workspace:
    port:
      - 6001:6001
  apache:
    container_name: web_one_apache
    image: webdevops/apache:ubuntu-16.04
    environment:
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
      WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN: web-one.localhost
      WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
    volumes: # Only shared dirs to apache (to be served)
      - ./public:/var/www/public:cached
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage:cached
    networks:
      - web-one-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  php-fpm:
    container_name: web-one-php
    image: php-fpm-laravel:7.2-minimal
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
      - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
      - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
      - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
    networks:
      - web-one-network
```

When I run "docker-compose up --build -d", it is giving me the following error.

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.workspace: 'port' (did you mean 'ports'?)
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it? How can I use Laravel Web Socket with docker-compose?

I tried changing from 'port' to 'ports', then I got the following error message instead.

```
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service workspace has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
```

Comment: did you try update 'port' to 'ports' on the fourth line?

Comment: Hi @AhmedAtoui, I just updated the question, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is wrong. A Dockerfile must start with a `FROM <image>` directive as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from). In your case it might be sufficient to run an existing `php:<version>-cli` image though, avoiding the whole Dockerfile stuff:

```
workspace:
    image: php:7.3-cli
    command: ["php", "artisan", "websockets:serve"]
```

Of course you will also need to add a volume with the application code and a suitable network. If you add a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of your services, you don't need to export the `ports` on your `workspace` either. Services may access other services as long as they are in the same network.